# ArcGIS 3D Security Camera Analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I found [a topic on Esri ArcGIS site](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/281/3d-security-camera-analysis) about using ArcGIS 3D Analyst for designing and placement of surveillance cameras, but there isn't any clear explanation to guide designer.

Is there any idea or guidance to use ArcGIS in this subject?

Comment: I'd be thinking of a viewshed http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000v3000000 or observer points http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Observer_Points/009z000000v1000000/ (where points represent doors, windows and potential hiding spots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the published "security camera design" schema to arcScene you first need to have an ArcGIS online account.

You should be able to:

1. Open ArcScene -> Go to File -> Sign In (ArcGIS Online)
2. Go to Geoprocessing toolbar - Search for Tools
3. In the Search Dialog switch from Local Search to ArcGIS Online
4. Click the ALL tab
5. Type in "Security Camera design"

Unfortunately, although this is how the service was added in the video you linked, it seems that it is no longer available.

Since designing detail buildings and architecural models in ArcGIS ArcScene requires an external 3D software such as Sketchup (no 3D editing or modelling is supported in ArcGIS) you could try building your 3D environment ground up in Sketchup (very intuitive and also free) then use a plugin such as the [AXis Camera Extension for Sketchup](http://www.axis.com/techsup/system_design_tools/camera_extension/) to "visualize the camera’s coverage in your SketchUp model."

Comment: Thanks @Jakub, as you have said, it is no longer available. I didn't find it.

Comment: I highly recommend using SketchUP for these types of applications. It's very intuitive and surprisingly powerful.